# How often does xy occur in a line of a txt file? In Python

Tags: python

I am provided with a txt file including lots of different letters.
e.g:

```
ab sbfdjd iojdig
ds fjk   sdfji oer
lkjäp   foküeeferf
```

How can I check how often for example the letter "j" was used in line 1, line 2 and line 3 and store this information in an array/list?

So for this certain example

```
print(NumberOfJInLine[0])
```

would output:

```
2
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def NumberOfStringInLine(index, string_to_find):
    print(string_to_find, lines_of_file[index])
    return lines_of_file[index].count(string_to_find)

def NumberOfJInLine(index):
    return NumberOfStringInLine(index, "j")


lines_of_file = open("text.txt", "r").readlines()
print(NumberOfStringInLine(0, "jd"))
print(NumberOfJInLine(0))
```

You don't need the other function I added but it adds flexibility.

Alternatively:

```
def AccumulateAppearances():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            yield line.count("j")

for n in AccumulateAppearances():
    print(n)
```

Comment: Why use `CamelCase` for function names?

Comment: I was trying being consistent with the question, not with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I'm not sure if that was the correct thing to do.

Comment: _I was trying being consistent with the question, not with PEP8. I'm not sure if that was the correct thing to do._ Unfortunately, the OP is often times unaware of PEP8/style conventions.

Answer (score 0):

```
seekLetter = "j"
occur = {}

with open("{your filename}", "r") as file:
    for nbLine,line in enumerate(file):
        occur[nbLine] = line.count(seekLetter)

for line in occur.keys():
    print("line {0} : ".format(line) + str(occur[line]) + seekLetter)
```

you can do it more easily with a dictionary